# reading xml file with multiple child node

Tags: java, xml, solr, xml-parsing

Consider i have a XML file like the below xml file.

```
<top>
    <CRAWL>
        <NAME>div[class=name],attr=0</NAME>
        <PRICE>span[class~=(?i)(price-new|price-old)],attr=0</PRICE>
        <DESC>div[class~=(?i)(sttl dyn|bin)],attr=0</DESC>
        <PROD_IMG>div[class=image]>a>img,attr=src</PROD_IMG>
        <URL>div[class=name]>a,attr=href</URL>
    </CRAWL>
    <CRAWL>
        <NAME>img[class=img],attr=alt</NAME>
        <PRICE>div[class=g-b],attr=0</PRICE>
        <DESC>div[class~=(?i)(sttl dyn|bin)],attr=0</DESC>
        <PROD_IMG>img[itemprop=image],attr=src</PROD_IMG>
        <URL>a[class=img],attr=href</URL>
    </CRAWL>
</top>
```

what i want is first take all the values coming under   and after finishing the first operation go to the next one and repeat it even though i have more than two  tag.I have managed to get if just one  is available. using the values coming inside the tags i am doing some other function. in each  it has values from different and i am using that values for different operations. everything else if fine other than i dont know how to loop the fetching inside the xml file.

regards

Comment: Just check out JAXB api examples - http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JAXB/article.html

Comment: What have you done so far?  Where do you stuck?  Show us where you need help with.

Comment: i am taking the values and crawling web site. so what i got inside the xml tags is the HTML properties i want to use for crawling. when i use multiple url i want to use multiple html properties for crawling ryt ? so i want to automate it . now what i am doing is using different xml files and manually changing the xml file name in the program to crawl. i want to give all the sites html properties into single xml file and read all one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding this correctly, you're trying to extract data from ALL tags that exist within your XML fragment. There are multiple solutions to this. I'm listing them below:

1. XPath: If you know exactly what your XML structure is, you can employ XPath for each node=CRAWL to find data within tags:

   ```
   // Instantiate XPath variable
   XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
   // Define the exact XPath expressions you want to get data for:
   XPathExpression name     = xpath.compile("//top/CRAWL/NAME/text()");
   XPathExpression price    = xpath.compile("//top/CRAWL/PRICE/text()");
   XPathExpression desc     = xpath.compile("//top/CRAWL/DESC/text()");
   XPathExpression prod_img = xpath.compile("//top/CRAWL/PROD_IMG/text()");
   XPathExpression url      = xpath.compile("//top/CRAWL/URL/text()");
   ```

At this point, each of the variables above will contain the data for each of the tags. You could drop this into an array for each where you will have all the data for each of the tags in all  elements.

1. The other (more efficient solution) is to have the data stored by doing DOM based parsing:

   ```
   // Instantiate the doc builder
   DocumentBuilder xmlDocBuilder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
   Document xmlDoc               = xmlDocBuilder.parse("xmlFile.xml");
   // Create NodeList of element tag "CRAWL"
   NodeList crawlNodeList = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CRAWL");
   // Now iterate through each item in the NodeList and get the values of 
   // each of the elements in Name, Price, Desc etc.
   for (Node node: crawlNodeList) {
        NamedNodeMap subNodeMap = node.getChildNodes();
        int currentNodeMapLength = subNodeMap.getLength();

        // Get each node's name and value
        for (i=0; i<currentNodeMapLength; i++){
             // Iterate through all of the values in the nodeList, 
             // e.g. NAME, PRICE, DESC, etc.
             // Do something with these values
        }
   }
   ```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Your 2nd solution (which is numbered as 1. too, btw), what is domFactory of a class?